# Is it possible to apply colors to text in mousepad text editor?

Tags: xubuntu, fonts, colors, mousepad

My OS is Xubuntu 16.04.5 and I would like to apply colors to text in mousepad text editor, is it possible? Do I need to download some plugin to that? It would be like a command > format font : type, size, color . Thanks Vladi.

Comment: I very doubt it.  It is a simple text editor, and handles only text.  Colors cannot be stored in text files unless saved in a non-text format that uses control or special characters to tell later programs what color to use, but that wouldn't be simple text anymore.  I tried loading an unusual file into mousepad, it didn't recognize it as text or UTF-8 & provided a drop-down of different ISO/charsets - but those were all formatting of text, and none allow for font/size/color which are not textual characters.

Answer (score 2):

I very much doubt it. It is a simple text editor, and handles only text. Colors cannot be stored in text files unless saved in a non-text format that uses control or special characters to tell later programs what color to use, but that wouldn't be simple text anymore. I tried loading an unusual file into mousepad, it didn't recognize it as text or UTF-8 & provided a drop-down of different ISO/charsets - but those were all storage-formats of text, and none allow for font/size/color which would involve non-textual characters.

From the XFCE docs  (xfce the missing manual)

> Mousepad (mousepad) is an Xfce implementation of Windows Notepad. This
>   will be very useful for temporarily saving small fragments of text,
>   opening files quickly for previews or writing large amounts of text.

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/xfce-the-missing-manual/latest/xfce-the-missing-manual.pdf

Since it mentions Notepad - Microsoft added a RTF (*rich text format*) file-format which allowed such extra information to be stored in a file, but it was proprietary,  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), no longer just text and later mostly abandoned as it was discovered the extra information also allowed malware to be used to infect windows systems.  By using simple text, you avoid any such negative issues, and these days many of us use *markdown* & other formats that are encoded in pure text anyway.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/
Edit an existing theme, give it a new name, and paste it into the Styles folder.
I give you an example with one of my themes.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1753dkuKaY8zAbdubwNLpT4WR0sDbNWKO/view?usp=sharing